# Python Swagger Trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, swagger

I have an oracle procedure that when receiving some parameters, throw results in a string with JSON format like the following:

```
{"list_pais": [ {"pais":"URUGUAY"},{"pais":"ARGENTINA"},{"pais":"PARAGUAY"},{"pais":"VENEZUELA"}] }
```

This procedure is invoked from a webservice in Python that I developed with FlaskResfutl to create the swagger and this is de code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import json
from app import APP
import log
import graypy
import database
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

with open('./config/config_countries.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

log.init()

#Se inicializa la base de datos
#Importando de database la conexión a la BD
database.init()

#Invoca al archivo de configuración
with open('./config/config_countries.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

with open('./config/config_general.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config_general = json.load(config_file)

srv_name = config["CONFIG"]["LOG_TAG"]
db_str = config["CONFIG"]["DB"]
max_return = config_general["CONFIG"]["MAX_RETURN"]
limite = config["CONFIG"]["LIMIT_PER_SECOND"]
api = Api(APP, version='1.0', title=srv_name,
          description='getCountries de Callejero Predictivo\n'
                      'Conexión a BD:' + db_str + '\n'
                      'Cantidad máxima de invocaciones por segundo:' + limite)

ns = api.namespace('getCountry', description='getCountries de Callejero Predictivo')


md_respuesta = {'pais': fields.String(required=True, description='Agrupador de Paises'), 'list_pais': fields.Nested(fields.String)}


@ns.route('/<string:country>')
@ns.response(200, 'Success')
@ns.response(404, 'Not found')
@ns.response(429, 'Too many request')
@ns.param('country', 'Introducir Cadena de Caracteres para el Pais')
class getCountryClass(Resource):
    @ns.doc('getCountry')
    @ns.marshal_list_with(md_respuesta)
    def post(self, country):
        try:
            cur = database.db.cursor()
            listOutput = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
            cur.callproc('PREDICTIVO.get_pais', (country, max_return, listOutput))
        except Exception as e:
            database.init()
            if database.db is not None:
                log.err('Reconexion OK')
                cur = database.db.cursor()
                listOutput = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
                cur.callproc('PREDICTIVO.get_pais', (country, max_return, listOutput))
            else:
                log.err('Sin conexion a la base de datos')
                listOutput = None


        return listOutput, 200
```

But when executing it, it generates the following error:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5200/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2018 15:52:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Unable to render schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 483, in __schema__
    self._schema = Swagger(self).as_dict()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\swagger.py", line 177, in as_dict
    paths[extract_path(url)] = self.serialize_resource(ns, resource, url, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\swagger.py", line 346, in serialize_resource
    path[method] = self.serialize_operation(doc, method)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\swagger.py", line 352, in serialize_operation
    'responses': self.responses_for(doc, method) or None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\swagger.py", line 464, in responses_for
    responses[code]['schema'] = self.serialize_schema(model)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\swagger.py", line 509, in serialize_schema
    'items': self.serialize_schema(model),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\swagger.py", line 529, in serialize_schema
    raise ValueError('Model {0} not registered'.format(model))
ValueError: Model {'pais': <flask_restplus.fields.String object at 0x00000189FFB94C88>, 'list_pais': <flask_restplus.fields.Nested object at 0x00000189FFB94F28>} not registered
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2018 15:52:22] "GET /swagger.json HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

and I can not find how to solve it.
Could someone give me clues to solve it?

Here the good versión in production without the swagger working 
https://github.com/alemarchan/sources_predictivo_prod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/flask_restplus/swagger.html and https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

The registered model can't be a dict, you need a model, try to replace

```
md_respuesta = {'pais': fields.String(required=True, description='Agrupador de Paises'), 'list_pais': fields.Nested(fields.String)}
```

by

```
md_respuesta = api.model('Pais', {'pais': fields.String(required=True, description='Agrupador de Paises'), 'list_pais': fields.Nested(fields.String)})
```

Comment: in the swagger appear again "No operations defined in spec!". I do not know what to do ;-(